# How to set Json array from flatlist in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, asyncstorage

I am new in react native . i am get data from asynstorage. how to set that data from flatlist. my problem is can not set value properly in flatlist data. herewith below attached the JSon value and my code. am try to long time but no idea for that please help me. please

> I get data to asystorage value Json Data

```
    {
   "users":[
      {
         "title":"Opna Women's Short Sleeve Moisture",
         "image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/51eg55uWmdL._AC_UX679_.jpg",
         "id":19
      },
      {
         "title":"DANVOUY Womens T Shirt Casual Cotton Short",
         "image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/61pHAEJ4NML._AC_UX679_.jpg",
         "id":20
      }
   ]
}
```

> Main code.

```
   import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, Alert, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import COLORS from '../../consts/colors';
import foods from '../../consts/foods';
import { PrimaryButton } from '../components/Button';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const CartScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState(true);


  AsyncStorage.getItem('storeddata')
    .then((value) => {
      setvalue(value)
      console.log("saveddata", value);

    }
    )

  const CartCard = ({ item }) => {
    console.log("itemlist", item);
    return (
      <View style={style.cartCard}>
        <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }} />
        <View
          style={{
            height: 100,
            marginLeft: 10,
            paddingVertical: 20,
            flex: 1,
          }}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, color: COLORS.grey }}>
            {item.title}
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>${item.id}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ marginRight: 20, alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 18 }}>5</Text>
          <View style={style.actionBtn}>
            <Icon name="remove" size={25} color={COLORS.white} />
            <Icon name="add" size={25} color={COLORS.white} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: COLORS.white, flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={style.header}>
        <Icon name="arrow-back-ios" size={28} onPress={navigation.goBack} />
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Cart</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 80 }}
        data={value}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <CartCard item={item} />}
        ListFooterComponentStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, marginTop: 20 }}
        ListFooterComponent={() => (
          <View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
                marginVertical: 15,
              }}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                Total Price
              </Text>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>$50</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 30 }}>
              <PrimaryButton title="CHECKOUT" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Checkout')} />
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
  cartCard: {
    height: 100,
    elevation: 15,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    marginVertical: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  actionBtn: {
    width: 80,
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
    borderRadius: 30,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default CartScreen;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `value` have that above `JSON` data stored then try to pass prop like:

```js
<FlatList
    ...
    data={value.users}
    ...
/>
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: not working. not show data in flatlist

Comment: or do that like `data = {value['users']}`. Also check if you're getting anything with `console.log(value.users)`

Comment: no, not getting value. console log file also could not print anything

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/zrOxY8QZp check this out. working fine there

Comment: item not working. console log not getting any data

Comment: its getting white screen only

Comment: check the node bundler, your logs will show there.

Comment: yes showing. but i try my code why not show that. i getting data from asynstorage directly and finally add to the flatlist data

Comment: now what i do that.

Comment: please help me anyone

Comment: Try to go with `react-native`'s `FlatList` Component, not `react-native-gesture-handler` and add this prop `keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}`

Comment: <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 80 }}
        data={value.users}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
         index.toString();
        }}
        renderItem={({item}) => <CartCard item={item} />}

Comment: no is not working .

Comment: `console.log` your `item` like this `renderItem={({ item }) => {console.log('item: ', item.title); }}` and show me what you're getting in this log

Comment: nothing to get that point, i think not call . its showing nothing(blank screen)

Comment: are you sure you have your JSON data stored in `value`?

Comment: yes sure,{"users":[{"title":"Opna Women's Short Sleeve Moisture","image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/51eg55uWmdL._AC_UX679_.jpg","id":19}]}

Comment: can you please connect anydesk?

Comment: please help me..

Comment: hard code is working, but get asynstorage data is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237932/discussion-between-shoaib-khan-and-kathir).

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('storeddata')
    .then((value) => {
      let cart=JSON.parse(value)
      setvalue(cart)
      console.log("itemlist", cart);
    }
    )
  }, [])

Comment: now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Flatlist data props take an array as an input [Official doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-data)

you are getting an object from local storage you have to pass an array to it

local storage save string value so you have to do `JSON.stringify()` it when you store data in it and `JSON.parse()` it when getting data from local storage
[local storage link](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage)

Comment: I am getting data is succesfully. but not working flatlist

Comment: the data you are getting is an object, you have to use 'users' key which is an array to the flatlist props.

Comment: how ? how to get users key . can you please tell

Comment: take your data in a new variable and then use temp['users']. temp is the name of your variable. you can check by console.log()

Comment: i am very sorry. i am a new. please edit my code. please

Comment: please edit my code. please

Comment: please help me...